# Extract parameters from `glue` string

Tags: r

Say I have the following string :

```
str1 <- "Isolated values : {x1}\nBasic operation: {x2+x3[2]}\nBase function: {cos(x4)}\nLoaded function: {str_sub(x5,1,5)}\nInexistent/unloaded/unaccessible function : {f1(x6)}\nUsing constants: {pi*x7}"
```

We define the parameters:

```
library(glue)
library(stringr)
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2
x3 <- c(2,3)
x4 <- 4
x5 <- "hello world"
x6 <- 6
x7 <- 7
f1 <- function(x){"I shouldn't exist"}
```

I can use glue and it works fine:

```
glue(str1)
# Isolated values : 1
# Basic operation: 5
# Base function: -0.653643620863612
# Loaded function: hello
# Inexistent/unloaded/unaccessible function : I shouldn't exist
# Using constants: 21.9911485751286
```

Now I modify the workspace a bit

```
rm(f1,x6)
```

I want to extract the parameters from this string and get the following output (order doesn't matter):

```
extract_glue_params(str1)
# [1] "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4" "x5" "f1" "x6" "x7"
```

I consider f1 as a parameter because it's not accessible from the current environment while `cos` or `str_sub` (from `stringr`) are.

`pi` is a constant so I want to ignore it as well.

I'm fine with the solution returning `"a"` or not for `glue("{data.frame(a=1)}")`, `glue("{x1$a}")` etc... I'll use it for simple cases in general.

The `glue` package does the parsing in `C` so I couldn't steal its code.